# Does the Netgear WNDA4100 support packet injection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm running Windows with Ubuntu 12.04 alongside in a dual boot configuration.

I was wondering if my new USB adapter supports packet injection? If so how do I get it to work in Ubuntu?